# Image Grid Won't Load Fullscreen With Internal Homepage Link Click

Tags: wordpress

My image grid on my Wordpress site for some reason does not resize fully to the max-width of the browser when I click an internal link to the homepage (eg. I click on an image then click back on the logo). It goes back to fullscreen when I resize the browser. It also works fine if I go into my website externally (from typing in the url). I have tried using:

```
#site {
max-width: !important;
}
```

but doesn't work. I'm not sure if if it is the theme that is the issue or one of my custom css. I have tried isolating some css with the inspector tool and seeing if any of them caused the problem but I couldn't find anything.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the full backend of the theme and I'm not a developer.

So if anyone has any idea that would be great!
Link is http://imconniehuang.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your image gallery's width is calculated and set by Javascript. Have a look at the surrounding `div.vc_row`, the width is set inline there. So no point in using CSS here. Seems like the script waits for a resize event to recalculate the gallery's width.

The prefix `vc_row` indicates that you are using *Visual Composer*. I think the problem is with this plugin. I therefore recommend getting support from the plugin provider-

BTW: 
`max-width: !important;` is not valid syntax. 'max-width' sets the maximum width of an element. You can [have a look at the syntax here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).